# What is the relevance of the algae dripping liquid?

Tags: analysis, aniara

Close to the end of the movie *Aniara*, there is a specific shot of maybe a few seconds that clearly have been added intentionally, but I'm not sure I understand the meaning fully.

> After Mimaroben received an award for her space beam, a set of bags containing algae is shown dripping liquid.

There is no further mention of this in the movie which ends perhaps a minute later. What is the meaning of this event in the context of what happens next?

My current best guess is it's expressing

> the level of decay and apathy of the society on board in that they are not even tending to their only remaining food supply. However, given that the next scene jumps 14 years later, with some passengers still alive, I'm not sure if this all there is to it.